# Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: , HTTP_UPGRADE: )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, actioncable, passenger-nginx

I've a Rails Application with nginx & passenger and i've followed the instructions [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/) but keep getting Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: , HTTP_UPGRADE: )

I've added the block below as docs suggest

```
location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name app_name_action_cable;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
}
```

but the error still exists and also i've tried all solutions here on stackover flow but no luck any help?

```
  redis: &redis
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

  development: *redis

  test: *redis

  production:
   adapter: redis
   url: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis_url] %>
```

Comment: What are you using as the adapter (e.g., Redis or Postgres)? Can you add your ``config/cable.yml`` to your question?

Comment: I'm using Redis

Comment: updated question with cable.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need some config in your nginx configuration? I do not really worked with passenger, but in my project I use it like:

```
  upstream socket_server {
    server <your_ip>:<your_port>;
  }

  location /cable {
     proxy_pass http://socket_server;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
```

I use [anycable](https://github.com/anycable/anycable) gem, with `golang` socket server, and it may have differences with `passenger` and default `actioncable` but may be my answer can help to rid of your problem

(Also, I strongly recommend to move on `anycable` because it is consumes the least server resources:))